# jquery ui tabs events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to call a function when a tab is loaded but it seems like the event never fires and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
    <div id="tabs" style="padding-top:0px;margin-top:0px">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-scripting">Scripting</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-scripting-history">Scripting History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-equipment">Equipment List</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-syslogs">Syslogs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-visio">Visio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-misc">Misc</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-visio">
    <img id="visio_topology" src="/Scripting/customer/7229_topology.png">
    <!-- Visio Tab div end -->
    </div>
```

JS:

```
  $('#tabs').tabs({
     select: function(event, ui) {
        window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;
     }
  });

  $("#tabs-visio").tabs().bind("tabsload", function(event, ui) {
     console.log('hello world');
  });
```

Using Firebug I never see 'hello world'. I'm new to jquery and I know I have to be missing something easy here I just cannot figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize `tabs` after binding to `tabsload` event handler. Try this

```
 $("#tabs-visio").bind("tabsload", function(event, ui) {
     console.log('hello world');
  }).tabs();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with jQuery UI Tabs but I had a look at your problem and this is what I found:

- Tabs specific events are triggered on the `#tabs` element.
- Event `tabsload` is triggered when the tab has external url. In that case content is loaded using AJAX and when AJAX request is successfull then `tabsload` event is triggered.
- In case of local or cached URLs only `tabselect` and `tabshow` events are triggered. So you should use one of those events.

Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems that you want to load some kind of big image when the tab is selected. In your example the img will be loaded right when the page is loaded. If you want to load image lazily then try this:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
      // if "Visio" tab is selected and the image is not in DOM ...
      if(ui.index === 4 && $("#visio-topology").length === 0) {
        // ... append it to the div
        $("#tabs-visio").append($("<img>", { 
          id: 'visio-topology', 
          src: '/Scripting/customer/7229_topology.png' }));
      }              
    }
});
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/eyapad/8/edit#javascript,live)** you can experiment with the events and see the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Is that really the whole of your HTML? If so, you're missing a closing tag on the #tabs div. The closing tag at the end of your HTML snippet is closing the #tabs-visio div.
Invalid HTML (if it really is) can upset jquery.

Comment: Wow, I just noticed that this question is over a year old. I hope you got it sorted in the meantime!